# Como Forçar Finalização uma Thread no Python?

Tags: python

Como forçar a finalização de uma Thread no Python?

Exemplo:

```
import threading


def funcao():
    print("Função executando em tarefa paralela.")
    print("Função executando em tarefa paralela.")
    print("Existem outras threads dela mas só essa tem que ser finalizada")
    print("Não vai ficar nenhum laço de repetição aqui checando condição para poder finalizar ela não, a finalização precisa ser forçada de fora")


threading.Thread(target=funcao).start()
```

Preciso forcar a finalização dela sem usar de macetes como return, break, raise, daemom, etc dentro da função que espera algo para poder finaliza-la. Mas sim de algo fora dessa função que a force terminar

Comment: Ah, você quer abortar o thread? Tipo, deixar tudo em estado inconsistente e simplesmente sair dele? Boa sorte! :)

Comment: @MarceloUchimura pode fazer um comentário um pouco mais construtivo e nos dizer o porquê de isso ser uma má ideia, e quais problemas pode trazer? (:

Comment: Só quem pode saber qual é o estado do thread é o próprio fluxo de execução no thread. Qualquer tentativa de _matá-lo_ de fora do contexto é a mesma coisa que tentar derrubar um avião de fora dele.

Comment: Preciso finalizar uma thread de um cliente socket sem timeout pre configurado para se conectar. O cliente é SSL. Mas as vezes o usuário insere um IP não SSL então o programa garra no wrap_socket e por não ter timeout pre configurado permanece garrado por bastante tempo. O usuario por ver que esta demorando clica no botão Stop do programa, a thread do listen que contem o accept() finaliza, pois esta em um while com condição de finalizar, mas o thread do cliente garrado não finaliza, e permanece.

Comment: Resolvi o problema. Coloquei um timeout de 30 segundos até de se conectar ao servidor, e uma vez tendo conectado retirei o timeout no I/O e o laço de repetição pode finalizar a thread quando quiser.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `asyncio`, em que corotinas/tarefas (`Task`) são semelhantes a threads mas não são realmente threads como definidas pelo SO, e então não têm problemas de mudança de contexto e nem de estado externo ao seu próprio programa.

Suponhamos que você queira calcular o quadrado de uma lista dos números de 0 a 4, mas quer cancelar a execução do cálculo de 2^2 se o resultado de alguma outra função for 9, sem ter dentro da corotina de cálculo nenhuma checagem, como você pediu.

Se faria assim com `asyncio`:

```
import asyncio
import random

# Função que simula algum trabalho de cada tarefa/corotina (semelhante a uma thread)
async def retornar_quadrado(n):
    if n == 2:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)  # A função que será cancelada demora mais.
    else:
        await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 2))  # As outras demoram de 0.5 a 2 segundos.
    return n ** 2


async def main():

    # Criar uma lista de tarefas
    tarefas = []
    for i in range(5):
        tarefa = asyncio.ensure_future(retornar_quadrado(i))
        tarefas.append(tarefa)

    for tarefa_completa in asyncio.as_completed(tarefas):
        try:
            n_quadrado = await tarefa_completa
            print(n_quadrado)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            continue

        # Se descobrimos que uma das respostas é 9, cancelamos tarefas[2]
        if n_quadrado == 9 and not tarefas[2].cancelled():
            print('Cancelando tarefas[2]...')
            tarefas[2].cancel()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Um exemplo de resultado:

```
16
9
Cancelando tarefas[2]...
0
1
```

Como pode ver, assim que encontramos o 9, cancelamos o cálculo de 2^2 e ele nunca foi exibido. Se remover a linha `tarefas[2].cancel()`, verá que o resultado `4` será exibido, e também que a função demorará os 10 segundos que esse caso especial requer.